# Extract the size information of a MATLAB 2D cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

```
>> Mat

Mat =

  3×1 cell array

    {1×4 double}
    {1×5 double}
    {1×6 double}
```

`Mat` is of type n-by-1 [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), and each element is of type 1-by-m cell array.

How to extract each element count of a 2D cell array into `num` without iterations?

```
>> num

num =

     4
     5
     6
```

I have tried [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) and [`numel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html), but they do not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
cellfun(@numel,mat)
```

Comment: Fabulous! Really simple! ;-)